# Text overflows parent div and break-word doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, word-wrap

I have a notification box that i am trying to fit into the view with @media property, but I can't seem to wrap the text inside the box. It overlaps when i set the screen to phone size for example.

Here is a picture of it happening: [image: overflow example]

I tried overflow-wrap: break-word; but it changes nothing. If I change the wrapper's idth to be 100% the only the green area fits itself into the area, but it has no effect on the text div

EDIT------->
as @Gaurav suggested, removing flex: 0 from content and text classes does help a bit, but it's not taking into account the content class's padding:
[image]

```js
.notification__wrapper_error {
  display: flex;
  flex - direction: row;
  align - items: center;
  padding: 0 px 8 px 0 px 0 px;
  gap: 20 px;

  width: 645px;
  height: 64 px;

  background: rgba(224, 30, 90, 0.1);
  border - radius: 0 px 8 px 8 px 0 px;
  border - left: 2 px solid# E01E5A;
}

.notification__icon_wrapper {
  margin - left: 10 px;
}

.notification__content {
  display: flex;
  flex - direction: row;
  align - items: flex - start;
  padding: 20 px 0 px;
  gap: 10 px;

  width: 636 px;
  height: 64 px;

  /* Inside auto layout */

  flex: none;
  order: 2;
  flex - grow: 0;
}
.notification__text {
  /* Contact */

  width: 636 px;
  height: 24 px;

  font - family: "Museo Sans";
  font - style: normal;
  font - weight: 400;
  font - size: 14 px;
  line - height: 24 px;
  /* identical to box height, or 171% */

  display: flex;
  align - items: center;
  text - align: center;

  /* Primary / Black */

  color: #000000;
  
    /* Inside auto layout */
  
    flex: none;
    order: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div hidden class="notification__wrapper_error">
  <div class="notification__icon_wrapper">
    <img class="notification__icon" src="$(LIBDIR)/images/notification/exclamation-white.png">
  </div>
  <div class="notification__content">
    <div class="notification__text">
      %body
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to fix it by removing `flex: none` from content and text classes and adding this bit of code

```html
  @media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    .notification__text {
        height: 100%;
      }
    .notification__content {
        padding: 10px 0px;
        height: 100%;
      }
      .notification__wrapper_error, .notification__wrapper_success, .notification__wrapper_info, .notification__wrapper_warning{
        height: 100%;
        gap: 5px;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove flex:none on class name `.notification__content` and `.notification__text`

Comment: that's a start, but it's not quite what I need. See the padding on he content class is not taken into account. Now it overflows content class but not outside of wrapper class